# Make all divs the height of the very first div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using this code

```
//Resize Div    
$(document).ready(function(){
    resizeDiv();
});

window.onresize = function(event) {
    resizeDiv();
}

function resizeDiv() {
    vpw = $(window).width();
    vph = $(window).height();
    $('.site-intro').css({'height': vph + 'px'});
}
```

It works great and makes the first div 100% of the window and set the height inline. Is there a way to add to this code so it would make other divs set to the same height?

I am placing one div on top of the other and want them all to be the same height (that same height being what ever 100% is).

Sorry,

The HTML

```
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="site-intro parallax" data-velocity="-.3">
    <div class="row-fluid header">
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-6 col-6 logo">
            <img src="img/logo.png" alt="" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-6 col-6 follow text-right">
            <a href="#"><img src="img/follow-fb.png" alt="Follow Us On Facebook" /></a>
            <a href="#"><img src="img/follow-tw.png" alt="Follow Us On Twitter" /></a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12"> 
                <h1 class="text-center">Website Success</h1>
                <h2 class="text-center">Is Dependent On Effort and Imagination</h2>
                <p class="text-center"><a class="text-center can-do" href="#">See What We Can Do For You</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to have more divs underneath the (.site-intro) not side by side. Then have links inside each div that will anchor to the next div.

Comment: We are going to need to see your HTML.

Comment: what you mean by `all divs`? Aren't they already `.site-intro` ? And BTW you can just do: `$('.site-intro').height( vph );` (just all of them need to share the same class, so I don't get your issue here.)

Comment: I don't see nothing wrong here: http://jsbin.com/UrAXIf/1/edit

Comment: `height:100%` ? If you just have `<div>`'s in the body, side by side, there shouldnt be a problem - but who knows, we dont know the markup.

Comment: And which of those `div` elements should be the same size as which *other* of those `div` elements? Just the `.row` elements, or the `col-lg-` elements?

Comment: I want the site-intro div and any other div I add in after that div to be the same height.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to say without seeing your DOM, but generally you can just use a multiple elements selector separated by commas.

Let's say you want to resize 3 elements:

1. `div` with class `site-intro`.
2. `div` with ID `user-data`.
3. `section` element.

The code will look like that:

```
function resizeDiv() {
    vpw = $(window).width();
    vph = $(window).height();
    $('.site-intro, #user-data, section').height(vph);
}
```

Comment: Comma separated did actually work, I have to test it in something other that FF. Another JS plugin I had must have been messing with it when I tried this at first, but you are correct.